# Zend Framework and Authorize.net integration

Tags: zend-framework, frameworks, integration, authorize.net

Has anyone ever built anything on the subject? Authorize.Net is one of the most widely used payment gateways so i'd image there would be a best practice and/or a solid resource for this integration. I wasn't able to find anything as reliable from my search. Any advise/resource/suggestion is greatly appreciated. "sharing is caring"

Answer (score 1):

The APIs for Paypal and Authorize.net are pretty straightforward. You wouldn't really need to use Zend specific methods to set them up within a Zend application. Magento, which is built on Zend, has an Authorize.net connection, you could take a look at that. Opencart is another open-source shopping cart that has an Authorize.net plugin. I have looked at that and it is decently written and easy to understand.

EDIT: Here's the class for Authorize.net AIM from Opencart (They have a SIM version as well). You should be able to make your own using this as a basis fairly easily.

```
class ControllerPaymentAuthorizeNetAim extends Controller {
    protected function index() {
        $this->language->load('payment/authorizenet_aim');

        $this->data['text_credit_card'] = $this->language->get('text_credit_card');
        $this->data['text_wait'] = $this->language->get('text_wait');

        $this->data['entry_cc_owner'] = $this->language->get('entry_cc_owner');
        $this->data['entry_cc_number'] = $this->language->get('entry_cc_number');
        $this->data['entry_cc_expire_date'] = $this->language->get('entry_cc_expire_date');
        $this->data['entry_cc_cvv2'] = $this->language->get('entry_cc_cvv2');

        $this->data['button_confirm'] = $this->language->get('button_confirm');

        $this->data['months'] = array();

        for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
            $this->data['months'][] = array(
                'text'  => strftime('%B', mktime(0, 0, 0, $i, 1, 2000)), 
                'value' => sprintf('%02d', $i)
            );
        }

        $today = getdate();

        $this->data['year_expire'] = array();

        for ($i = $today['year']; $i < $today['year'] + 11; $i++) {
            $this->data['year_expire'][] = array(
                'text'  => strftime('%Y', mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, $i)),
                'value' => strftime('%Y', mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, $i)) 
            );
        }

        if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/payment/authorizenet_aim.tpl')) {
            $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/payment/authorizenet_aim.tpl';
        } else {
            $this->template = 'default/template/payment/authorizenet_aim.tpl';
        }   

        $this->render();        
    }

    public function send() {
        if ($this->config->get('authorizenet_aim_server') == 'live') {
            $url = 'https://secure.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll';
        } elseif ($this->config->get('authorizenet_aim_server') == 'test') {
            $url = 'https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll';       
        }   

        //$url = 'https://secure.networkmerchants.com/gateway/transact.dll';    

        $this->load->model('checkout/order');

        $order_info = $this->model_checkout_order->getOrder($this->session->data['order_id']);

        $data = array();

        $data['x_login'] = $this->config->get('authorizenet_aim_login');
        $data['x_tran_key'] = $this->config->get('authorizenet_aim_key');
        $data['x_version'] = '3.1';
        $data['x_delim_data'] = 'true';
        $data['x_delim_char'] = ',';
        $data['x_encap_char'] = '"';
        $data['x_relay_response'] = 'false';
        $data['x_first_name'] = html_entity_decode($order_info['payment_firstname'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        $data['x_last_name'] = html_entity_decode($order_info['payment_lastname'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        $data['x_company'] = html_entity_decode($order_info['payment_company'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        $data['x_address'] = html_entity_decode($order_info['payment_address_1'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        $data['x_city'] = html_entity_decode($order_info['payment_city'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        $data['x_state'] = html_entity_decode($order_info['payment_zone'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        $data['x_zip'] = html_entity_decode($order_info['payment_postcode'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        $data['x_country'] = html_entity_decode($order_info['payment_country'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        $data['x_phone'] = $order_info['telephone'];
        $data['x_customer_ip'] = $this->request->server['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $data['x_email'] = $order_info['email'];
        $data['x_description'] = html_entity_decode($this->config->get('config_name'), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        $data['x_amount'] = $this->currency->format($order_info['total'], $order_info['currency_code'], 1.00000, false);
        $data['x_currency_code'] = $this->currency->getCode();
        $data['x_method'] = 'CC';
        $data['x_type'] = ($this->config->get('authorizenet_aim_method') == 'capture') ? 'AUTH_CAPTURE' : 'AUTH_ONLY';
        $data['x_card_num'] = str_replace(' ', '', $this->request->post['cc_number']);
        $data['x_exp_date'] = $this->request->post['cc_expire_date_month'] . $this->request->post['cc_expire_date_year'];
        $data['x_card_code'] = $this->request->post['cc_cvv2'];
        $data['x_invoice_num'] = $this->session->data['order_id'];

        /* Customer Shipping Address Fields */
        $data['x_ship_to_first_name'] = html_entity_decode($order_info['shipping_firstname'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        $data['x_ship_to_last_name'] = html_entity_decode($order_info['shipping_lastname'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        $data['x_ship_to_company'] = html_entity_decode($order_info['shipping_company'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        $data['x_ship_to_address'] = html_entity_decode($order_info['shipping_address_1'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . ' ' . html_entity_decode($order_info['shipping_address_2'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        $data['x_ship_to_city'] = html_entity_decode($order_info['shipping_city'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        $data['x_ship_to_state'] = html_entity_decode($order_info['shipping_zone'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        $data['x_ship_to_zip'] = html_entity_decode($order_info['shipping_postcode'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        $data['x_ship_to_country'] = html_entity_decode($order_info['shipping_country'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

        if ($this->config->get('authorizenet_aim_mode') == 'test') {
            $data['x_test_request'] = 'true';
        }   

        $curl = curl_init($url);

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PORT, 443);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data, '', '&'));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);

        $json = array();

        if (curl_error($curl)) {
            $json['error'] = 'CURL ERROR: ' . curl_errno($curl) . '::' . curl_error($curl);

            $this->log->write('AUTHNET AIM CURL ERROR: ' . curl_errno($curl) . '::' . curl_error($curl));   
        } elseif ($response) {
            $i = 1;

            $response_info = array();

            $results = explode(',', $response);

            foreach ($results as $result) {
                $response_info[$i] = trim($result, '"');

                $i++;
            }

            if ($response_info[1] == '1') {
                if (strtoupper($response_info[38]) == strtoupper(md5($this->config->get('authorizenet_aim_hash') . $response_info[6] . $this->currency->format($order_info['total'], $order_info['currency_code'], 1.00000, false)))) {
                    $this->model_checkout_order->confirm($this->session->data['order_id'], $this->config->get('config_order_status_id'));

                    $message = '';

                    if (isset($response_info['5'])) {
                        $message .= 'Authorization Code: ' . $response_info['5'] . "\n";
                    }

                    if (isset($response_info['6'])) {
                        $message .= 'AVS Response: ' . $response_info['6'] . "\n";
                    }

                    if (isset($response_info['7'])) {
                        $message .= 'Transaction ID: ' . $response_info['7'] . "\n";
                    }

                    if (isset($response_info['39'])) {
                        $message .= 'Card Code Response: ' . $response_info['39'] . "\n";
                    }

                    if (isset($response_info['40'])) {
                        $message .= 'Cardholder Authentication Verification Response: ' . $response_info['40'] . "\n";
                    }               

                    $this->model_checkout_order->update($this->session->data['order_id'], $this->config->get('authorizenet_aim_order_status_id'), $message, false);             
                }

                $json['success'] = $this->url->link('checkout/success', '', 'SSL');
            } else {
                $json['error'] = $response_info[4];
            }
        } else {
            $json['error'] = 'Empty Gateway Response';

            $this->log->write('AUTHNET AIM CURL ERROR: Empty Gateway Response');
        }

        curl_close($curl);

        $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @JeremyC I'm required to do this with ZF and Authorize.net. I was just looking over the API from Authorize.net .. How would you incorporate it into Zend MVC structure though? Would you register the Authorize.net.php into Zend's autoloader or would you do `require_once("PATH/Authorize.net.php");` in a specific action controller where the cc processing goes on?